# Struggling with slicing over strings and using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, string, list-comprehension, slice

I am currently working on a pandas dataframe from a dataset, which includes export and import revenues from and to Germany from 2012 on. For the sake of clarity I would like to add another column "Continents" and assign to every country its location. My dataframe is sorted by country and year. A snippet looks like this:

| Country | Code | ... | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | ST423 | ... | 4 <-- desired result |

The third character in "Code" defines the continent: 1 for Europe, 2 for Africa, 3 for Americas, 4 for Asia, 5 for Oceania. I am trying to fill the "Continent" column with the continent names.

What I tried is first to create a list of the series "Code"

```
codelist = df["Code"].to_list()
```

then I tried (after failing to achive my goal) at least to add the numbers to that column, so the third sign in each values in "Code". But even here I am failing to do so:

```
[codelist[x][2] for x in range(0,len(codelist)-1)]
```

It states:

`"IndexError: string index out of range"`

which I don't understand, since

`codelist[0][2]`  and `codelist[len(codelist)-1][2]`  both give positive results.

Comment: That error suggests that you have an item somewhere in the Code column that is not long enough, so the `[2]` is out of range. `codelist[0][2] ` works because the first item in your dataframe does not have this problem, but it seems that one does further down.

Also (unrelated to the error) I don't think you want to subtract 1 from `len(codelist)` in your range. `range(x, y)` doesn't include the last value, e.x. `range(0, 3)` gives `[0, 1, 2]`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I got the error; there were indeed two-character long entries, which is why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Tha'ts because the column `Code` contains for sure at least one string with a length shorter than 3.

```
       Country   Code
0  Afghanistan  ST423
1            A     ST
2            B   None
3            C    XXX

      1 codelist = df["Code"].to_list()
----> 2 [codelist[x][2] for x in range(0,len(codelist)-1)]

IndexError: string index out of range
```

You can instead use [`str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)/[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
d = dict(enumerate(["Europe", "Africa", "Americas", "Asia", "Oceania"], 1))

df["Continent"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Code"].str[2], errors="coerce").map(d)
```

Another variant with [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
df["Continent"] = df["Code"].str.extract(
            "..(\d)", expand=False).astype("Int8").map(d)
```

Or, if you prefer a *listcomp*, you can fix your code by adding an `if/else` statement :

```
df["Continent"] = [
    d.get(int(c[2])) if c and len(c)>2 and c[2].isdigit()
    else None for c in df["Code"] # <-- change None if needed
]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

       Country   Code Continent
0  Afghanistan  ST423      Asia
1            A     ST       NaN
2            B   None       NaN
3            C    XXX       NaN
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Country': ['Afghanistan', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
     'Code': ['ST423', 'ST', None, 'XXX']}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, somewhere you have a `Code` that is less than 3 characters.  If you don't mind having an empty string for the Continent, it's easy to fix:

```
[codelist[x][2:3] for x in range(0,len(codelist)-1)]
```

It's a funny thing about slicing.  If you ask for a single index that doesn't exist, you get an `IndexError`.  But if you ask for a *range* that doesn't exist, you get an empty result.  So just use a range with a length of a single character.